# cygwin: diff.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygsigsegv-2.dll

Tags: dll, cygwin

I installed the latest cygwin x86-64.  I added diffutils to get the basic diff(1) linux command.   When I now run it, I get:

```
diff.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygsigsegv-2.dll
```

I did a search for the dll [here](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=%20cygsigsegv-2.dll&arch=x86_64), but there are zero matches, not found.

I then re-ran the installer and did a search in the installer search box on this dll, and nothing came up.

Can you please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cygsigsegv-2.dll` is part of package `libsigsegv2`, which is required by
`diffutils`:

```
@ diffutils
sdesc: "A GNU collection of diff utilities"
category: Utils
requires: cygwin libiconv2 libintl8 libsigsegv2
```

Installing that package should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks Steven, would you please tell me where you did that  @ diffutils  "command".   I can't do it in the Bash shell, so I'm curious where you did that.

Comment: When I search on libsigsegv2 in the Cygwin Setup tool, nothing is found. ...  I see the issue:  because I'm not supposed to download unapproved software on my company machine -- an old 32 bit version of cygwin is approved (that's it, not a 64 bit), I keep doing searches based on my original local 64 bit install, instead of going back out on the internet.   When I do that, libsigsegv2 is not found (locally), but I see it on the internet mirror site.